# Data Visualization and Multiple Linear Regression in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a big project to work on and the dataset is classified so I am just going to use my own example so everyone can understand what I am targeting.

Let's take Target as an example:
We consider three brands of tape: Target brand, 3M and Avery.
The original data frame has 4 columns: Year of Record, Product_Name(which contains three brands of tape), Sales, and Region.

The original data frame will look like this:

```
   Year of Record      Product_Name        Sales       Region
     2018              Target_Brand        2000$        Midwest
     ...                ...                 ...          ...
     2018               Avery               9000$       Central America
```

I want to create a visualization based on, for instance, region, sales, etc.

Should I use barplot?

**Second question**

My R code says this when I run multiple regression model:

> > data = read.excel(...)
> >     data1 = subset(data, Product_Name == "Target Brand")
> >
> > model = lm(Product_Name ~ ., data1)

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

How can I approach this scenario?

(P.S: My real dataset has about 36 columns and I truncate down to 21 columns. That is why I use the notation ~.)

I need help. Please give me guidance.

Comment: The reproducible example is not complete. Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Chris I did post a sample. Please let me know if I can help clarify my question better. Thanks all!

Comment: It looks like the original dataset is already in the perfect form for the analysis you wish to perform

Comment: @Chris My goal is that I want to look at the Target Brand variable, analyze the data set (decision tree analysis maybe?) to make a decision whether I should invest more Target brand in Mid-west or Central america. I am trying to profile data to provide a good data visualization.

Comment: @AdamRalphus your data is in so called 'tidy' form already with each column representing a variable - perfect for analysis with `dplyr` and `ggplot2` for example. If you have a specific visualization/ analysis in mind then maybe consider a more pointed question.

Comment: @Chris Hello Chris, is this a good place to have follow up question or should I create a new post?

Comment: If it is a different question then make a new one, if still similar then edit. Be sure to provide a reproducible example to help people to provide an answer

Comment: @Chris I edited my post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172260/discussion-between-chris-and-adam-ralphus).